# MySql - Update the values of a column for certain rows based on the values of another column

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Well i have a situation, which i will explain with an example below

**Column 1    Column 2   Column 3**

```
   1       87       0
   6       89       0
   8       87       1
   9       87       0
  15       89       0
  18       90       1
```

so i have a case such that, the column3 value is unique for the same values of column2

so here lets consider column2 value as 87. So we have 3 such records, but i want a unique value for these three records in column3. So i mean there should be only one of these three records to have the value 1 in column3 and the rest should be having it as 0.

So lets say i want to update the value of column3 for these set of records to 1, where the column1 value is 9 and set the value of column3 to 0 when the column1 value is 8 and column2 value is 87. So i am unable to figure out how to do this.

I tried by resetting all the column3 values to 0 if the column2 value is 87 and then update the particular required record. But that's not happening. Any other possible solution??

Comment: Show us what you have done so far

Comment: update table set column3 = '0' where column2 = '87';

after executing this statement then 

update table set column3 = '1' where column1 = '9';

Comment: dont bother with complex sql if youre not familiar with this. instead, write simple sql queries and do your calcution using php loops.

Comment: Does that first update successfully set both rows to 0?

Comment: @Stuart no thats not happening....i don't understand the reason....

Comment: What is the datatype of your columns?  In your example SQL you're single-quoting values, but if they're numeric then you shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: well ok got it....there was someother issue from the other table which was troubling the issue.....now got it solved....thnx nyways